# Java Json Object to Json Array Conversion

Tags: java, arrays, json, spring-security

Im new to java.I am trying to get data from stored procedure and convert it into json array. But Im facing some problems with my code.

```
           /*** Get data from stored procedure ***/
           Map<String, Object> out =  simpleJdbcCall.execute(in);
           /*** Convert to JSONObjects ***/
           JSONObject jsonRes = new JSONObject();
           jsonRes.put("body", out.get("#result-set-1"));
           System.out.println(out.get("#result-set-1"));

output :

          [{user_id=484, user_name="abc", email=null, contact_no=123456789}, 
           {user_id=485, user_name=xyz, email=null, contact_no=235612354}]

Expected output :

          {
            "body":
                "Data":{
                        {
                         {user_id=484, user_name="abc", email=null, contact_no=123456789},
                         {user_id=485, user_name=xyz, email=null, contact_no=235612354}
                        }
                       }
           }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using HashMap You can nest as many elements(HashMaps) as you want. Here is an example

```
Map<String, Object> out =  simpleJdbcCall.execute(in);    
Map<String, Object> users = new HashMap<String, Object>();

users.put( "0", out.get("#result-set-1") );
        
Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
data.put( "Data", users );
Map<String, Object> body = new HashMap<String, Object>();
body.put( "body", data );
       
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.putAll( body );
System.out.printf( "JSON: %s", json.toString(2) );
```

Answer (score 0):

In your last line, print `jsonRes` instead of `out.get("#result-set-1")`:

```java
System.out.println(jsonRes);
```

Then you will see something closer to what you expect, probably pretty similar to:

```
{
 "body": [
   {user_id=484, user_name="abc", email=null, contact_no=123456789},
   {user_id=485, user_name=xyz, email=null, contact_no=235612354}
 ]
}
```

If it works out like this, then `body` is the `JsonArray`

Comment: Hi, the body looks like an object. but i need results like :
{
 "body": {
   {user_id=484, user_name="abc", email=null, contact_no=123456789},
   {user_id=485, user_name=xyz, email=null, contact_no=235612354}
 }
}

Comment: Hi Kiran, what do you get when you print jsonRes?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use ObjectMapper(Jackson)

```
String output = <Stored_Procedure_Output>;
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
ArrayNode arrayNode = objectMapper.readValue(output, ArrayNode.class);
for(int i=0;i<arrayNode.size;i++){
   JsonNode obj = arrayNode.get(i);
   // You can use the obj to retrieve each object
}
```